# Wrong resolution when setting nomodeset in /etc/default/grub, right when entered manually

Tags: graphics, ati, fglrx, display-resolution, 15.10

I just can't wrap my head around this. I've been trying to install Linux (yesterday Arch, today Ubuntu) for quite some time now. I had graphics issues every single time. Mostly bsod a few seconds after logging in, rarely directly on boot.

Now I finally got it to work on 15.10, but only when I *manually* add "nomodeset" to kernel parameters. If I set it in /etc/default/grub and run "sudo update-grub", the resolution is set to 1024x768. Also, I am using the open-source radeon driver, because the release notes say so.
What is going wrong here?

Really getting frustrated, especially because Ubuntu has mostly worked flawless for me. How do I fix this?

Also, I haven't yet found out how to set my refresh rate to 144hz.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nomodeset` is a tool to get your graphics working properly, not the solution. As such, I wouldn't be worrying about the resolution you're getting.
You need to boot with `nomodeset` and figure out how to fix your drivers, most likely by either: updating the open-source one (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`) or by installing the proprietary driver (you should be able to do this from the 'Additional Drivers' application that comes with Ubuntu by default).
Good luck!