Ubuntu Keeps crashing after 24.04 update
I have Ubuntu installed along with windows dual booted on my Dell Latitude e6410. After the 24.04 update Ubuntu crashes a few minutes after booting. (screen freezes, mouse locks up, no HDD activity). Windows seems to work normally. I tried to reinstall it using a live USB of 24.04 and the Live USB also crashed in the same exact way. Tried to use safe graphics and it installed just fine (no crashing). After the re-installation it started crashing again. I was able to go to proprietary drivers before it crashed and none are in use. I should also point out that Ubuntu worked just fine before the update. Any tips?
Update: hardware specs: 4 GB ram with an intel core i5 520m with intel hd graphics. it was a distribution upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 LTS. The laptop is a dell latitude e6410. the upgrade proceeded normally (no errors) and the problem started after rebooting
There is nothing in the /var/crash folder. Also the problem is not overheating related, since the system does not shut down it just freezes. Also i should point out, the only way for it not to crash is by booting into recovery then selecting resume. the resolution is wrong but no crash (maybe graphics driver releated?). Here is the full output from the journalctl -b -1 -e pastebin. Pastebin ending contents shown below:

(... beginning lines snipped due to size limit ...)


May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: kerneloops.service: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[952]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.50' (uid=1000 pid=1503 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop whoopsie[2059]: [18:35:04] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop (rneloops)[2061]: kerneloops.service: Referenced but unset environment variable evaluates to an empty string: DAEMON_ARGS
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Starting geoclue.service - Location Lookup Service...
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Started kerneloops.service - Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[952]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
May 23 18:35:04 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Started geoclue.service - Location Lookup Service.
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.32' (uid=1000 pid=1503 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop nautilus[2102]: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop snapd-desktop-i[2055]: New theme: gtk=Yaru-dark icon=Yaru cursor=Yaru, sound=Yaru
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop snapd-desktop-i[2055]: All available theme snaps installed
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' unit='xdg-desktop-portal.service' requested by ':1.76' (uid=1000 pid=2102 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service" label="nautilus (unconfined)")
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service...
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service' requested by ':1.77' (uid=1000 pid=2125 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.Screencast'
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[952]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service' requested by ':1.80' (uid=1000 pid=1667 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-keyboard" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service - GNOME color management service.
May 23 18:35:05 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.target - GNOME color management target.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service - GNOME keyboard configuration service.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.target - GNOME keyboard configuration target.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Starting systemd-localed.service - Locale Service...
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service - GNOME power management service.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.target - GNOME power management target.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service - GNOME keyboard shortcuts service.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.target - GNOME keyboard shortcuts target.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service - GNOME Wacom tablet support service.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.target - GNOME Wacom tablet support target.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target gnome-session.target - GNOME Session.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target gnome-session-wayland@ubuntu.target - GNOME Wayland Session (session: ubuntu).
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Reached target graphical-session.target - Current graphical user session.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: gnome-initial-setup-first-login.service - GNOME Initial Setup was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=!/home/john-karpontinis/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done).
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner...
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service - Portal service (GNOME implementation)...
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[952]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Started systemd-localed.service - Locale Service.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Successfully made thread 1530 of process 1503 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level 0.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Successfully made thread 1530 of process 1503 owned by '1000' RT at priority 20.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop tracker-miner-f[2142]: Could not create store: Database version is too old: got version 0, but 28 is needed
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Failed to start tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop gsd-media-keys[1668]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop gsd-media-keys[1668]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating service name='org.gnome.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1.49' (uid=1000 pid=1672 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-power" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: GNOME Shell started at Thu May 23 2024 18:35:03 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Registering session with GDM
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Launching DING process
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner...
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop tracker-miner-f[2184]: Could not create store: Database version is too old: got version 0, but 28 is needed
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 23 18:35:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Failed to start tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome'
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner...
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service - Portal service (GNOME implementation).
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop rtkit-daemon[1346]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service' requested by ':1.77' (uid=1000 pid=2125 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop tracker-miner-f[2209]: Could not create store: Database version is too old: got version 0, but 28 is needed
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Failed to start tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.88' (uid=1000 pid=2185 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.88' (uid=1000 pid=2185 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service...
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner...
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk'
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation).
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop'
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: (gjs:2185): Gjs-WARNING **: 18:35:07.746: GLib.unix_signal_add has been moved to a separate platform-specific library. Please update your code to use GLibUnix.signal_add instead.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: 0 DesktopManager() ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/desktopManager.js":263:12]
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: 1 anonymous() ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/ding.js":180:25]
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: 2 anonymous() ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/ding.js":197:20]
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: 3 <TOP LEVEL> ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/ding.js":206:12]
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop tracker-miner-f[2233]: Could not create store: Database version is too old: got version 0, but 28 is needed
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Failed to start tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: ** Message: 18:35:07.892: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: DBus interface for Switcheroo control (net.hadess.SwitcherooControl) is now available.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: DBus interface for Gvfs daemon (org.gtk.vfs.Metadata) is now available.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files' unit='tracker-miner-fs-3.service' requested by ':1.76' (uid=1000 pid=2102 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service" label="nautilus (unconfined)")
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner...
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: DBus interface for Nautilus (org.gnome.Nautilus.FileOperations2) is now available.
May 23 18:35:07 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: DBus interface for Nautilus (org.freedesktop.FileManager1) is now available.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: Received notification for window. 0 notifications remaining.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: DBus interface for File-roller (org.gnome.ArchiveManager1) is now available.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop tracker-miner-f[2261]: Could not create store: Database version is too old: got version 0, but 28 is needed
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Failed to start tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop gnome-shell[1503]: DING: GNOME nautilus 46.0
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 23 18:35:08 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Failed to start tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner.
May 23 18:35:16 UbuntuLaptop ModemManager[1105]: <msg> [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3] creating modem with plugin 'generic' and '1' ports
May 23 18:35:16 UbuntuLaptop ModemManager[1105]: <wrn> [plugin/generic] could not grab port ttyS4: Cannot add port 'tty/ttyS4', unhandled port type
May 23 18:35:16 UbuntuLaptop ModemManager[1105]: <wrn> [base-manager] couldn't create modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3': Failed to find primary AT port
May 23 18:35:19 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Finished plymouth-quit-wait.service - Hold until boot process finishes up.
May 23 18:35:19 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Reached target multi-user.target - Multi-User System.
May 23 18:35:19 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Reached target graphical.target - Graphical Interface.
May 23 18:35:20 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Starting setvtrgb.service - Set console scheme...
May 23 18:35:20 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Starting systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service - Record Runlevel Change in UTMP...
May 23 18:35:20 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Finished setvtrgb.service - Set console scheme.
May 23 18:35:20 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice - Slice /system/getty.
May 23 18:35:20 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 18:35:20 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Finished systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service - Record Runlevel Change in UTMP.
May 23 18:35:20 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Startup finished in 2.142s (kernel) + 27.954s (userspace) = 30.096s.
May 23 18:35:25 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 18:35:25 UbuntuLaptop systemd-timesyncd[754]: Contacted time server 185.125.190.58:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 23 18:35:25 UbuntuLaptop systemd-resolved[750]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
May 23 18:35:25 UbuntuLaptop systemd-timesyncd[754]: Initial clock synchronization to Thu 2024-05-23 18:35:25.623112 EEST.
May 23 18:35:29 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 18:35:35 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 18:35:35 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 18:35:41 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started app-gnome-x\x2dterminal\x2demulator-2293.scope - Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
May 23 18:35:42 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.100' (uid=1000 pid=2296 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --wait" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:42 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Created slice app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice - Slice /app/org.gnome.Terminal.
May 23 18:35:42 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server...
May 23 18:35:42 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
May 23 18:35:42 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server.
May 23 18:35:42 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started vte-spawn-21acb7ec-a5ab-4f87-9300-03d0cdae2d72.scope - VTE child process 2310 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 2302.
May 23 18:35:45 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=9999 txrate=52000
May 23 18:35:46 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=9999 txrate=52000
May 23 18:35:47 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-61 noise=9999 txrate=52000
May 23 18:35:49 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Disassociation Imminent - Disassociation Timer 0
May 23 18:35:49 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Preferred List Available
May 23 18:35:50 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Disassociation Imminent - Disassociation Timer 0
May 23 18:35:50 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Preferred List Available
May 23 18:35:50 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Disassociation Imminent - Disassociation Timer 0
May 23 18:35:50 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Preferred List Available
May 23 18:35:50 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Disassociation Imminent - Disassociation Timer 0
May 23 18:35:50 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: WNM: Preferred List Available
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 94:b2:71:c7:4e:21 (Reason: 8=DISASSOC_STA_HAS_LEFT)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=94:b2:71:c7:4e:21 reason=8
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: BSSID 94:b2:71:c7:4e:21 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.3849] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.4848] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31 (SSID='GEOPOLIS_ESTIES' freq=5700 MHz)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: authenticate with 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31 (local address=58:94:6b:43:e1:78)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: send auth to 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31 (try 1/3)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.6716] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31 (SSID='GEOPOLIS_ESTIES' freq=5700 MHz)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: authenticated
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: waiting for beacon from 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.8032] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: associate with 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31 (try 1/3)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31 (capab=0x1501 status=0 aid=1)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: associated
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: Associated with 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31 completed [id=0 id_str=]
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=GR
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.9143] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.9144] device (wlp2s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.9145] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.9145] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.9145] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478551.9146] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 23 18:35:51 UbuntuLaptop kernel: wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 94:b2:71:c7:4e:31
May 23 18:35:52 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478552.0123] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=10.17.4.88, acd pending
May 23 18:35:52 UbuntuLaptop NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1716478552.0127] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=10.17.4.88
May 23 18:35:52 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[952]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=1007 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:35:52 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 23 18:35:52 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[952]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 23 18:35:52 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 23 18:35:52 UbuntuLaptop wpa_supplicant[1012]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=9999 txrate=6000
May 23 18:36:03 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started app-gnome-ubuntu\x2dadvantage\x2dnotification-2325.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
May 23 18:36:03 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started app-gnome-update\x2dnotifier-2329.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
May 23 18:36:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Consumed 1.168s CPU time.
May 23 18:36:06 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started app-gnome-x\x2dterminal\x2demulator-2398.scope - Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
May 23 18:36:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.110' (uid=1000 pid=2401 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --wait" label="unconfined")
May 23 18:36:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Starting gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server...
May 23 18:36:07 UbuntuLaptop dbus-daemon[1325]: [session uid=1000 pid=1325] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
May 23 18:36:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server.
May 23 18:36:07 UbuntuLaptop systemd[1300]: Started vte-spawn-a81228b0-ec86-4cf8-9a25-5b19968fc25a.scope - VTE child process 2414 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 2407.
lines 707-1004/1004 (END)


The question lacks details. What are the hardware specs? What was the update?

hardware specs: 4 GB ram with an intel core i5 520m with intel hd graphics. it was a distribution upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 LTS. The laptop is a dell latitude e6410. the upgrade proceeded normally (no errors) and the problem started after rebooting.

@john karpontinis Unfortunately we can not see what caused the crash. There can be many reasons, pls read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068720/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-crash-reason and all the links that are included in it and then post with relevant info so that someone can help.

There is nothing in the /var/crash folder. Also the problem is not overheating related, since the system does not shut down it just freezes. Also  i should point out, the only way for it not to crash is by booting into recovery then selecting resume. the resolution is wrong but no crash (maybe graphics driver releated?). Here is the output from the journalctl -b -1 -e command:

https://pastebin.com/J0b835cH                 (had to use paste bin cause the log is big)

I suggest that instead of answering in comments, you edit your question with all the info you got and the link to pastebin, and read this https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

@Jos I also upvoted and edited. People who down-vote should leave a comment. Also unless otherwise obvious, people should leave comment on why they are close-voting.

@WinEunuuchs2Unix forget about this broken voting system. Thankfully Google still finds the most relevant page if you ask it nicely

I read from another post that one should try editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to disable wayland by uncommenting the line WaylandEnable=false.

I can't believe you accept the complete reinstallation as the answer. There is no way in hell that should be the answer. That is like you go get a head transplant because you have a headache. That is just nuts.

One of the worst mistakes I've ever made was installing Ubuntu 24.04. It's caused me to lose a lot of work. Does anyone know a way to revert? To downgrade to version 22.04?

And it's really annoying. Any app crashes randomly

Update: I reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04 and everything works correctly! (no crashing). So they most likely released an update thru software updater that fixed the problem.

That is just total bull crap that every time you have to reinstall the whole thing. That can't be the solution seriously. It is like if you catch a cold and the doctor tells you to have a lung transplant.

Besides, if john karpontinis is right then getting the updates every day should sort the issue out without a wholesale reinstallation. As of September 3rd, this is not yet happening . . .

I had the exact same problems with 24.04, similar HW setup, 4GB RAM and an Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 560 with Intel Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller i915 (Thinkpad T410).
The problem was solved by adding nomodeset to the kernel parameters.
(uptime >1h while using Plasma X11 with firefox, thunderbird, ...)
I had some flickering in Plasma wayland, but it still worked without any freezes.
Either edit the grub command line while booting or make it permanent by changing /etc/default/grub, more specifically the following line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume nomodeset" (and of course run sudo update-grub after the edit)
Update:
@WinEunuuchs2Unix and @john karpontinis
Good question, IIRC I took this "solution" from the same link as in john's comment (#2)
And I put solution in "", because yesterday I didn't worry about the wrong resolution so much (mine was not so far off from the native monitor resolution - 1280x800 instead of 1440x900). But today I understand that nomodeset prevents the actual drivers from being used (I can't even change that later after X loaded), so it's not a real solution in the end.

@raphha2 I tried that and the seems like the graphics driver does not work (resolution stuck very low) but no crashing! (so that pretty mutch confirms its a driver issue?). unfortunately i cant keep it like this, its pretty mutch unsuable with that low of a resolution. Tried this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/690705/wrong-resolution-when-setting-nomodeset-in-etc-default-grub-right-when-entered but no luck

@john karpontinis have you tried this site https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download-center/home.html may be they have the driver

@amar yeah, unfortunately they have only Windows drivers... i might revert back to 23.10 but that might mess up my windows dualboot so idk. I will probably wait a few weeks just in case i am lucky and they release something thru software updater

@john karpontinis one more place to try https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu they should know if a driver is missing

@john karpontinis also put the name and model of your grafic card in the question

@amar I did it but no answers so far :(

@john karpontinis Do not worry it might take 2 or 3 days they got a lot of things to do but they will get back to you. Just make sure that when you answer them your question turns to open again, do not use add comments button.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2062951

@amar this bug looks related, thank you for the link!
However there is no mentioning of a system freeze and for me the suggested kernel parameters didn't solve the problem discussed here.

@john karpontinis add yourself to the bug if it effects you. John we still do not know if your grafik is I915.

@amar my graphics are the integrated intel HD graphics  I don't think i am affected by the bug since i don't have any  flickering,  it just that the system freezes after 30s to 1 min after booting

@amar update, i do indeed have I915 driver, but strangely no flickering, just the crashing. I am probably going back to 23.10 for now

@john karpontinis when you decide to upgrade- it is best to clean up your computer so much you can before you update, remove all old programs you do not need if you did not change anything in them, Take a look at your ppas and clear those that are not needded, and if you think of anything else to clear.

@amar will do! And obviously for now on I will create backups before any major updates...

nomodeset causes black screen of death for me.

Since the original topic is a crashing 24.04 and not "how to fix the kernel/driver", I dare to add that a practical solution for me is to simply use an older kernel. I still had uname -r: 6.5.0-28-generic hanging around from my 23.10 installation I upgraded from, which works fine.
If you don't have older kernels lying around, I think you can find them here, e.g. for the 6.5.0-series:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/6.5.0-35.35
or (temporarily) add another file (e.g. "mantic.list") in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with contents
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic-security main

and install the linux-(header|image|modules|modules-extra)-6.5.0-..-generic packages from the 23.10 "mantic" repository

Pls add yourself to the bug report if it affects you.

@amar, sure, I already did!

For me the problem simply came from the fact that I installed fuse,
and that it updated part of the grub and it does not support the architecture and this type of
kernel,
architecture,environment  in ubuntu 24.04 lTS and causes an error :
I So I was in recovery by tapping crtl + fn + command + escape,
on MacBook-Pro 2011,
and I typed these commands :
`cat ~/.bash_history

cat ~/.bash_history
and I saw it :
fuse updated the grub and created a bootloop which I recovered with this simple series of commands in my case
`
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt remove fuse
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo reboot
REBOOT OK WITHOUT LOSING DATA :)
Conclusion :
I managed to enter recovery by tapping on all the buttons until I found the one that worked all the time I hope this could have helped you !

Hard to believe that fuse a feature that affects storage devices would have anything to do with video issues.

Same happened to me on 24.04 after installing fuse because it was needed ay Arduino IDE 2. Uninstalling helped!

At this point i think the easiest solution to get my laptop  functional   is to revert back to 23.10.1 for now, at least until the support ends at July 2024. Hopefully there would be some kind of fix thru software updater until then.
Edit: for some reason i could not format my ubuntu partition (the format checkbox was grayed out) using the live USB, so i had to go to drive manager in Windows, delete my ubuntu partition, then from the live USB installer create the ext4 partition and install Ubuntu on it. Then, after the installation run sudo update-grub in terminal (so i can boot windows thru the grub menu)

July 2024?  There has been talk here that while Ubuntu 24.04 was released in April 2024, those who want the most stable version should wait for the first 'point' release, which is scheduled for Auguest 2024.

@quill according to this: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle 23.10 expires in July, at least for "standard support"

Ran into this problem myself with a T410 but with the Nvidia chipset
It seems to be down to Wayland and GDM interacting, my fix was to disable Wayland completely in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncomment this line
#Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
Been stable since

Thanks for idea but isn't it just unacceptable that years after other major distros have successfully implemented Wayland we are back to Ubuntu failing yet again to integrate Wayland with other core packages ? Is Ubuntu trying to extort Mozilla or what ?

Hello, I tried Xorg mode, but Ubuntu still crashes (Even on Xorg mode) on my GPD Win 2, they need to fix that.
